# What's the best way to call a function from a generic class with a shared function

Tags: c#, generics, switch-statement

I'm trying to figure what would be the best way to call a function off of a generic class.

```
public T Create<T>(T obj)
{
    switch (obj.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "Bank":
            (new Bank()).Create(obj);
            break;
        case "Bar":
            (new Bar()).Create(obj);
            break;
        case "Beer":
            (new Beer()).Create(obj);
            break;
        default:
            (new Broke()).Create(obj);
            break;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

I have like 30 classes, so it would be a pretty ugly big switch statement that would be tough to manage and I have to pass in around 100,000 obj. Also it's CRUD so I got to do it 4 times. Reflection is a little on the slow side. So far I've been sitting here at my desk with a giant frowny face trying to think of a good way.

I asked my good friend Alexa, Siri, and Google, but they weren't all that helpful. Normally I'm able to get all the answers I need from one of them...

### 2 days later

I did a poor job of explaining at the time. But I went ahead with the giant switch and a simplified version looks like this. With the CreateEntity function overloaded accepting each of the different classes.

```
public Entry Create<T>(T obj, ObjBuilder builder)
{
    Entry entry;
    switch (obj)
    {
        case Profile p:
            entry = builder.CreateEntity(p);
            break;
       case Area a:
            entry = builder.CreateEntity(a);
            break;
        case Credential c:
            entry = builder.CreateEntity(c);
            break;
        case Device d:
            entry = builder.CreateEntity(d);
            break;
    }
    return entry;
}
```

Comment: I think that at some point you will have to do the switch. A slightly better syntax would be `case Bank bank: bank.Create();break;` (C# >= 8.0, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Couldn't you cast the result of `Create` directly to `T`?  Something like  `return (T)obj.Create();`  I guess it depends on if `T` is the target type, or some shared type.

Comment: since they're all having `Create()` method, does that mean they share also an `interface` which implements `Create()` ?

Comment: Why is the method generic at all if you're not using `T` in it?

Comment: The edited code maybe makes more sense, except...if `obj` is a `Bank` then you instantiate another `Bank` with which to `Create()`...something (yet another `Bank`? or does `Create()` just copy the properties from the parameter?), and then you `return` not whatever was created but the original input (`obj`), anyways?  Is this `Create<T>()` method supposed to just clone the input object?  It'd be helpful if you explained what the desired code is supposed to do and the types involved because this might not be the best approach and the example is unclear.

Comment: I did a very poor job of showing what I was trying to do. Basically I'm being send objects that need to map to other objects. So I might be sent an object with some bank information that needs to be remapped into my Bank Class. The object may be information with someone's favorite bar. that needs to remap to the Bar Class.

Comment: Is your "2 days later" code an answer to your question or an updated question?

Comment: What does CreateEntity do? Can you please show its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at using a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` to make this work. It might seem complicated, but it gives you the ability to add any number of types at run-time.

Here's the code:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _creators = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

public Entry Create<T>(T obj, ObjBuilder builder) =>
    _creators.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
    ? ((Func<ObjBuilder, T, Entry>)_creators[typeof(T)])(builder, obj)
    : null;

public void Register<T>(Func<ObjBuilder, T, Entry> factory)
{
    _creators[typeof(T)] = factory;
}
```

Now just register your factories:

```
Register<Profile>((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x));
Register<Area>((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x));
Register<Credential>((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x));
Register<Device>((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x));
```

Easy.

Or you can hard-code the dictionary like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _creators = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()
{
    { typeof(Profile), (Func<ObjBuilder, Profile, Entry>)((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x)) },
    { typeof(Area), (Func<ObjBuilder, Area, Entry>)((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x)) },
    { typeof(Credential), (Func<ObjBuilder, Credential, Entry>)((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x)) },
    { typeof(Device), (Func<ObjBuilder, Device, Entry>)((b, x) => b.CreateEntity(x)) },
};
```

Or you can do a combination of both.

---

Here's the way to do this with the original code you had:

```
void Main()
{
    Register<Bank>(obj => (new Bank()).Create(obj));
    Register<Bar>(obj => (new Bar()).Create(obj));
    Register<Beer>(obj => (new Beer()).Create(obj));
    Register<Broke>(obj => (new Broke()).Create(obj));
}

private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _creators = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

public T Create<T>(T obj)
{
    if (_creators.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        ((Func<T, T>)_creators[typeof(T)])(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}

public void Register<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    _creators[typeof(T)] = action;
}
```

Comment: I think without knowing what `ObjBuilder`'s `CreateEntity` our answers are a guesswork.

Comment: What is the benefit of using a dictionary and not a switch statement? I think the switch statement is clearer.

Comment: @tymtam - The primary benefit is that you can update the dictionary at run-time. It allows you to dynamically build your switch. You can add types from any assembly, so it makes plugins easier. You can use reflection to build the dictionary so you don't need to write so much code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have all your entities implement the same interface.

```
public interface ICreateable<T> {
    T Create();
}

public class Bank : ICreateable<Bank> {
    public Bank Create()
    {
        return new Bank();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Not really sure what the use case is though.

Comment: Sorry I had to edit the code so this is no longer relevant. This would have been the good solution for the way I originally worded it.

Comment: @JustinNeff - Please don't change questions to invalidate existing answers. If you are changing your question then please create a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to slice the problem the following way?

```
public class EntryData
{
int X { get; }
int Y { get; }
}

public interface IEntryData {
   EntryData GetEntryData();
}

public class Profile: IEntryData {
   ...
   public EntryData AsEntry();
}


public class Area: IEntryData {
   ...
   public EntryData AsEntry();
}

...

Option 1:

public Entry Create(object obj, ObjBuilder builder) {
   if(obj is not IEntryData) {...}
   
   IEntryData entryData = obj as IEntryData;

   builder.CreateEntity(entryData);
}

Option 2: 

public Entry Create(IEntryData obj, ObjBuilder builder)  
   => builder.CreateEntity(entryData);
...

class ObjBuilder {
   Entry CreateEntity(IEntryData entryData) {
      // Other things
      var extra = ...

      return new Entry(
         x: entryData.X,
         y: entryData.Y,
         z: extra.Z)
   }
```

Comment: For your Option 1 you could just have `public Entry Create(IEntryData obj, ObjBuilder builder)`. Your "Please note" says that the generic `T` is not needed, but now your method requires a concrete `T`.

Comment: I also have no idea what you're doing in your option 2.

Comment: Pass in `IEntryData` (not `object`)

Comment: Sorry - in option 1 I meant to fully get rid of T.

Comment: I don't know what the `return new Entry(x: entryData.X y: entryData.Y z: extra.Z` code i. It's not valid C# syntax and I don't know where `X`, `Y`, `Z` come from.